# split a full name to first name and last name in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

so basically i'm learning pyspark
and i know how to split full name to first name and last name in python

```
name = "sun moon" 
FName = name.split()[0]
LName = name.split()[1]
```

i want to do this in pyspark file json

```
{"l":"santee, california, united states","t":"161xxxx","caseN":"888548748565","caseL":"CA","n":"sun moon"}
```

my code

```
    df = spark.read.json("cases.json")
    df.select("l","t","caseN","caseL","n")
    df \
   .write \
   .mode('overwrite') \
   .option('header', 'true') \
   .csv('cases')
```

i want to split **n** to FName and Lname

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

df = spark.read.json("cases.json")
df.select("l","t","caseN","caseL","n")\
.withColumn("FName", split(col("n"), " ").getItem(0))\
.withColumn("LName", split(col("n"), " ").getItem(1))\
.write \
.mode('overwrite') \
.option('header', 'true') \
.csv('cases')
```

Comment: hey thank you what if the user has three name in row "sun moon earth" how we can handle this

Comment: you can use regexes, if you know which space is the important one

Comment: pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract(str, pattern, idx)

Comment: first, *last = col("n").split()
not working
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html  this is the regex  \s

Comment: u can use pyspark.sql.functions.slice to slice the output of split and then rejoin it

Answer (score 1):

No you can just do it this way:

sname = name.split(" ")
The above line chops the name whenever it encounters space.

Fname = sname[0]
Lname = sname[-1]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to split the `n` item inside the json.

Answer (score 0):

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import split,size,col
df2=(spark
     .createDataFrame(
       [
         ("f1 f2","l1 l2 l3"),
         ("f1","l1 l2"),
         ("f1 f2 f3","l1 l2 l3 l4")
       ],
       ["first_name","last_name"]
     )
    )

(df2
.withColumn("last_name_size",size(split(col("last_name")," ")))
.withColumn("first_name2",split(col("first_name")," ").getItem(0))
.withColumn("last_name2",split(col("last_name")," ").getItem(col("last_name_size")-1)).show())
```

The result is

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|first_name|  last_name|last_name_size|first_name2|last_name2|
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|     f1 f2|   l1 l2 l3|             3|         f1|        l3|
|        f1|      l1 l2|             2|         f1|        l2|
|  f1 f2 f3|l1 l2 l3 l4|             4|         f1|        l4|
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

what I did was simply create an auxiliary column with last_name split size
and with that it is possible to get the last item in the array

Answer (score 0):

If df is the data frame where customer's full name is in column CUST_NAME (For ex:- VIKRANT R THAKUR) then the following code format will work :-

```
df1 = df.withColumn('FIRST_NAME', initcap(substring_index('CUST_NAME', ' ', 1)) )
```

-> VIKRANT

```
df1 = df.withColumn('LAST_NAME', initcap(substring_index('CUST_NAME',' ',-1)) )
```

-> THAKUR